# $_REQUEST becomes empty after upgrade to php7.4 from php5.2

Tags: php

I have a Ext.FormPanel with some Ext.form.Hidden items and use getForm().submit to send request to server. When php5.2 was used, $_REQUEST can get all of the items. But after upgraded to php7.4, $_REQUEST becomes empty except those in "url".

If requests are sent to server with Ext.Ajax.request, there is no problem at all.

I really need help. Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
php.ini has following values:
upload_max_filesize = 40M
request_order = "GP"
variables_order = "GPCS"
post_max_size = 35M
```

Here is the form:

```
details = new Ext.FormPanel({
    method:'POST',  
    fileUpload:'true',
    url:'../action.php5',
    items:[
    {
    xtype:'fieldset',
    border:true,
    labelWidth:60,
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;background-color:#F2F2F2;',
    height:80,title:'Image',
    layout:'form',width:600,items:[fileupload]}
    },
    new Ext.form.Hidden({name: '_page', value:'serverPage'}),
    new Ext.form.Hidden({name: '_action', value:'update'}),
    ],
            
    buttons: [{
    text: 'Apply',
    handler : function() {
    upgradeImage();
    }
    }]

function upgradeImage(){
    details.getForm().submit({                      
    waitMsg:'please wait...',
    method:'POST',
    timeout:1200*1000,
    success:function(form, action) {
    var result = Ext.decode(action.response.responseText);
    ...
    }
    failure:function(form, action){
    ...
    }
}
```

And nothing from:

```
print_r($_REQUEST, true);
```

Comment: Instead of using $_REQUEST try using $_POST and see if you get results.

Comment: $_POST is also empty.

Comment: I guess this problem is more related to your php ini settings -> request order. You can check out the comments here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: both request_order and variable_order have been set:  request_order = "GP"
variables_order = "GPCS"

Comment: Just figured out, if I remove fileUpload:'true' from the formPanel, the form data can be seen in $_REQUEST, but  $_FILE is empty.

Comment: He says it's ExtJS 2.2.1. I cannot even find docs about that version. Sorry.